# Adjusting Range Value without For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove the left character from a column of strings without looping over each cell, but I'm getting an error in Excel. Here is my code, can I do this without a for loop?

```
Public Sub TestRngAdjust()
 Dim TestRNG As Range
 Set TestRNG = Range("A1:A5")
 TestRNG.NumberFormat = "@"
 TestRNG.Value = Right(TestRNG.Value, Len(TestRNG.Value) - 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: I would put the full range into a variant array, iterate that making the changes then assign the array back in the range.  It will be very quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loops are not bad.  They are bad when looping ranges on worksheets.
Use variant arrays to loop.

Using Variant method:

1. load range into a variant array.
2. loop the array and make changes.
3. assign variant array data back to range.

```
Public Sub TestRngAdjust()
 
 Dim TestRNG As Range
 Set TestRNG = Range("A1:A5")
 
 Dim rngarr As Variant
 rngarr = TestRNG.Value
 
 Dim i As Long
 For i = 1 To UBound(rngarr, 1)
    rngarr(i, 1) = Mid$(rngarr(i, 1), 2)
 Next i
 TestRNG.NumberFormat = "@"
 TestRNG.Value = rngarr
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Lightning fast answer w/ Lightning fast code! Thanks!

Comment: Why did you use MID vs Right?

Comment: vba Mid does not need the third criterion of length.  If omitted it will assume the end of the string.  That way I do not need the `Right() - Len()`

Comment: Ahh I understand, MID starting at 2nd position = Right(Str,Len(Str) -1

Comment: Even though this is more code, I find it more readable to me and I see you tested speed

Comment: This definitely deserves to be the accepted answer (and needs some more upvotes)!

Comment: @BigBen yours actually answers the question, mine is just showing, what I feel is a better way.

Comment: Your answer also answers the question, I was specific in the question that I didn't want to loop over cells, not that I just didn't want to loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to loop:

```
Dim s As String
s = "RIGHT(" & TestRNG.Address & ",LEN(" & TestRNG.Address & ") - 1)"
TestRNG.Value = TestRNG.Parent.Evaluate(s)
```

But really, it's very easy to read the data into a `Variant` array, use `Right` on each element, then write the array back to the range.

Comment: BTW tested on full column.  Variant took 1.3 seconds and the evaluate 1.5 seconds to do the full column.

Comment: Blergh @ScottCraner hahaha of course you would.

Comment: I had always been curious on which would be quicker.  Thought this a good test.